# Apache ISIS isis-module-security default user/password

Tags: isis

What is the proper way to either delete, disable or at least change the default password of the 'isis-module-security-admin' by means of code or configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module defines the [SeedSecurityModuleService](https://github.com/isisaddons/isis-module-security/blob/master/dom/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/module/security/seed/SeedSecurityModuleService.java#L41) that runs the [SeedUsersAndRolesFixtureScript](https://github.com/isisaddons/isis-module-security/blob/master/dom/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/module/security/seed/SeedUsersAndRolesFixtureScript.java#L52) that in turn sets up the account [isis-module-security-admin](https://github.com/isisaddons/isis-module-security/blob/master/dom/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/module/security/seed/scripts/IsisModuleSecurityAdminUser.java#L25) account.

Currently this isn't configurable, but you could raise a PR against SeedSecurityModuleService where the IsisModuleSecurityAdminUser fixture script could use an @Inject ConfigurationService to read the value of the name to use from a config property, eg "isisaddons.module.security.adminUserName"

HTH
Dan

Comment: I have created ModuleService & FixtureScript, but my module never called from application start up. what else should I do?

Comment: I want to add `org` and `domianapp` to `isis-module-security-admin` by default on application startup.

Comment: Each service is initialized by its @PostConstruct, eg in [SeedSecurityModuleService](https://github.com/isisaddons-legacy/isis-module-security/blob/master/dom/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/module/security/seed/SeedSecurityModuleService.java#L41).  To get the service itself picked up, the AppManifest needs to include its package (or a superpackage), derived from a module.  If you're still struggling, I suggest you push an example app to github repo and I'll pull it down to take a look.

Comment: Thank, I have done it now. I get the sample from platform.incode.org